# Android Studio Installation doesn't find JDK?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up Android Studio on my new laptop and running into some difficulty. I get prompted to provide a path for the JDK, which I downloaded from the oracle website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

[image]

But I get this message when I press `Next`:

[image]

jdk1.7.0_79 definitely has bin/java.exe in it, I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any insight is highly appreciated

Comment: try removing the bin directory and address only jdk1.7.0_79

Comment: Forgot to mention it but I tried this already

Answer (score 0):

Go to : 
`My Computer->Right Click->System Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment variables`

Under user variables Click New.

`Variable Name : JAVA_HOME
Variable Value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`

Apply and then Ok.
Then start installing android studio.
If it still doesn't work,download and install jdk 1.8.0_45